# Why can't doctrine purge my database? Syntax error with doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine

I keep getting this error whenever I try to load my data fixtures:

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]                                                
  An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM Group':                   

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error i  
  n your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server v  
  ersion for the right syntax to use near 'Group' at line 1
```

I don't want to modify doctrine, but obviously it's not using the correct syntax. Do I need to configure doctrine differently? I am using smyfony2 with mysql and the basic doctrine bundle. Bellow is my composer.json file:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "doctrine/orm": "*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "dev-master",
    "ircmaxell/password-compat": "dev-master"
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Group` is a keyword in `mysql`. so you might want to escape it.

```
DELETE FROM `Group`
```

Comment: Yep, this is the second time I've stupidly made this mistake. Thanks!